# Anyone know if there is a service to validate UK student card numbers?

Tags: discount

Not entirely sure if this is the right place for this question, but here goes.

I have tried getting in touch with the UK NUS people, but so far had no response, to the question of whether there any web services available to validate a UK NUS (National union of students) discount card.

I think these are 18 digit codes, but don't even know how to broadly parse them as I've no idea what they're based on.

I know Topshop, amongst other businesses offer this on checkout from their site, applying the discount into the cart process, which we'd also like to do... It's just I can't find anything at all on this.

Feel free to LMGTFY if I've missed some search term that points directly at the relevant information.

**EDIT**
It seems the topshop site, and a few others are actually validating against a third party company https://www.myunidays.com/ . I would have thought this could be a fairly lucrative business for the NUS to get into. Feed subscription to partnered businesses would be a real money spinner in my opinion. Guess it's either the third party route then, or wait until hell freezes over.

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm fairly sure you've already tried the optimum route.  Blagging NUS numbers seems to be a common problem.  There are plenty of reports of people going onto TopShop, etc, just entering a random 18 digit number.

That suggests to me that they don't have a credit card style checksum.  Even if they did, you'd still only know that the number was mathematically correct.  No guarantee that the card is still active.

Comment: It seems the NUS do have some business services but they're not something you can just hook up to. We're currently awaiting a decision by them now, so I'll update if I ever hear back regarding validation services.

Answer (score 0):

NUS provide a web interface to validate against.  We have implemented this for clients as a magento extension.  Contact NUS Extra Tel: 07974 646 112